# Angular JS onblur event not working on chrome

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In my application on blur event is not working on chrome though its working on IE-9.

For on blur functionality i have written

```
angular.element('#outerDiv').live('blur', function (e) { }
```

Please let me know what is the way to work with onblur in chrome.

Actually i want to apply onblur on **Div**. In that Div on dynamic iframe is generating and in that iframe the text area comes and i am able to write any text.

**My AngularJS version in 1.2.15**

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://api.jquery.com/blur/ -- you could just call `angular.element("#outerDiv").on('blur', function(event) {})`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Let me check the solution you provided

Answer (score 1):

You should use [ngBlur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)

> Specify custom behavior on blur event.

*HTML*

```
<input ng-blur="yourScopeMethod()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
angular.element('#outerDiv').live('onblur', function (e) { }
```

Comment: try this , this should be work                                     $( "#outerDiv" ).blur(function() {
 alert( "Hello World" );
});